# AngularJS/Dynamic <svg> not compiling into DOM in Microsoft IE 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

My problem is that my AngularJS (latest v1.X) can't add to the DOM svg elements I'm generating from it in IE.

I have no errors showing in the dev console. My app is loaded (and thus, the controller), since the width and height of the svg container are set by Angular.

The application is working fine on Firefox, Chrome, Tablets Chrome and Android browser...

**My directive :**

```
'use strict';
My_App.directive('ngHtmlCompile', ["$compile", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtmlCompile);
            }, function (value) {
                element.html(value);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**My HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="My_App" ng-controller="App">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My App</title>
        <style>
            * { margin:0; padding:0; @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'); font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; } /* Retire les espaces autour du canvas */

            html, body { width:100%; height:100%; } /* Override le comportement des navigateurs */

            svg { display:block;background-color: dimgrey;} /* Retire la scrollbar */

            svg text {
                cursor: default;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            ::selection, ::-moz-selection{background: none;}

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MyApp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="MyApp" ng-cloak ng-attr-width="{{svg.width}}" ng-attr-height="{{svg.height}}" ng-html-compile="html"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller side, my $scope.html is updated once at startup with a XHR request, then every 5 seconds after it.th ngHtmlCompile is then called to read it, and add the html stored in as childrens of svg.

If anything is missing, you can ask me. First post, so feel free to tell me if I did anything wrong on my request. And last, sorry if my english is broken, I'm French.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: On IE you can't use the .html() method to create SVG elements. The specification changed to support this after IE11 was shipped. Newer browsers do therefore support this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm glad to know where's the problem is located now. Any solution for it to work on IE11 then ? I could use a canvas, but it would mean rewritting evey draw function to support canvas.

Comment: Can't I just use a ng-view, and use an app to build svg elements in an html file ? I should try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like a comment above said (thanks to [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson)), the **html() function doesn't work on IE 11**. It just doesn't even appear in dev console that something is wrong.

As a solution (mainly, I just did it another way), I used the **ngRoute module** for angular.

The index.html is now only a container of a `<div ng-view>` tag, and my `<svg>` is placed in an include.html. In this, you can use any `$scope` var in any attribute, and you're done.

I'm not accepting this answer as long no one can tell that we **can't generate html on IE11**, as it was my original purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If appears as if you can use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `Element.html()`.  It seems to work on IE11.

```js
var svgStr='<svg><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/></svg>';

var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', svgStr);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: It works... for elements without `{{scopeVar}}` . Any idea of how to compile it then ? And the DOM is broken, every html tag is created inside the previous one... Seems like the 'afterbegin' is recursive.